# Marshal.SizeOf of a structure showing wrong output

Tags: c#, struct, types, sizeof

Here's my code:

```
struct abc
{
    short a;
    byte b;
    int c;
}
```

When I use:

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(abc)));
```

It shows: `8` whereas it should show: `7` because in my machine: byte: `1`, short:`2`, int:`4` bytes respectively.

Why is it happening?

If it is happening due to padding, how to disable the padding while reading the size of the structure? Because i need the exact size of the structure in bytes. It's important.

Comment: You understand that wire size and memory size are possibly different, right?

Answer (score 9):

It's showing `8` because of [structure member alignment rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

If you want to set your `struct` as unaligned, you need to use `StructLayout` with the `Pack = 1` attribute like so:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct abc
{
    short a;
    byte b;
    int c;
}
```

This should output `7`.

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YIhW2V) for those that are interested.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But do i have to use the line: [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)] before every structure i define?

Comment: @SayanSen That's right, if you want to set the structure as unaligned.